# Why do environment variables fail in my sonar config?

Tags: sonarqube, openshift

I'm trying to get sonar to work on OpenShift. When i try to use environment variables in the sonar.properties file they are not resolved by sonar.

The results look something like:

```
2013.06.18 17:22:19 INFO  o.s.c.p.Database  Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://${env:OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_IP}:${env:OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_PORT}/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
2013.06.18 17:22:20 ERROR o.s.c.p.Database  Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_IP}:${env:OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_PORT}"'.)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549) ~[commons-dbcp-1.3.jar:1.3]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388) ~[commons-dbcp-1.3.jar:1.3]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[commons-dbcp-1.3.jar:1.3]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:140) [sonar-core-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:69) [sonar-core-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_19]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_19]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_19]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_19]
```

I'm trying to understand how the variable resolution in sonar works so i can begin to figure out what is wrong on OpenShift.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Sonar running using git://github.com/wenhao/openshift-sonar.git with a slight modification:

- deleted the default jbossews sample app (git rm -r pom.xml src/ webapps/ROOT.war
- only copied over the ROOT/ ,  sonar-3.3.1/ , and .openshift/action_hooks/pre_start_jbossews-1.0 from the repo
- renamed pre_start_jbossews-1.0 to pre_start_jbossews  (due to changes in v2 cartridge renaming)
- modified ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/sonar-war.properties:

  #SONAR_HOME=${env:OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/webapps/sonar-3.3.1
  SONAR_HOME=/var/lib/openshift/51c0c3c1e0b8cd74800000dc/app-root/repo/webapps/sonar-3.3.1
- git add .
- git commit/push

I'm not quite sure why ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/sonar-war.properties doesn't resolve the env variable, but sonar-3.3.1/conf/sonar.properties resolves them just fine:

```
sonar.jdbc.username:                       ${env:OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}
sonar.jdbc.password:                       ${env:OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD}
```